# JS on ajax-loading pages getting out of sync with server-side code and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website that loads mostly using AJAX calls. The javascript and CSS files are only loaded once when the page first loads.

My issue is that the javascript/CSS can get out of sync with the HTML and server-side code. The page can be using an old versions of the javascript file (from when the page first loaded) while the server-side code and ajax-loaded HTML files always use the latest code and files.

**What are some strategies for dealing with this?**

I have considered polling the server at set intervals and asking if there is a newer version of the JS. Then, if there is, reloading the page. But, it seems that this can get ugly, with the page suddenly reloading at awkward moments instead of, for example, as the result of a user-initiated call.

Also, there are some changes to the javascript that do not necessarily require that a page be reloaded. For example, the changes might affect a different page/module than the one that the user is on.

Re-loading the javascript with every Ajax call is not viable

I can imagine ugly solutions to this, but thought I'd ask first.

**EDIT (in response to comments and suggested answers)**

The only way to get the JS back into sync is to reload the page, which then loads the new JS. Adding new JS to an old page won't work as it doesn't get rid of any old functions, listeners, etc. I'm not asking how to reload a page or how to load javascript. I'm asking for a strategy of knowing WHEN to do it, especially in a way that does not seem awkward to the user. Do people incorporate polling to ask if there is a new JS version? Do they then suddenly (from the user's point of view) reload the page? Do they poll even when the tab is hidden? Is this a problem for the server? Where do they keep track of the latest required JS version? Or, do they ask with every AJAX request - hey, should I reload? Did they write a special function for that? Do they keep all new html/server code backwards compatible with the js?

Someone who has dealt with this, how do you do it?

Comment: Difficult to determine whats issue is? Can you include `html`, `js`, `css` at Question?

Comment: The user loads a page and the javascript is loaded. Now, I update the server-side code and the JS to match, for example, sending more parameters along with an AJAX call. The issue is that the user who loaded the page before the changes is still using the old JS, but is reaching the new server-side code. The result in this particular case is that the server function does not get the expected parameters.

Comment: Still not gathering entirely, though you could call `$.getScript()` to load new `js` at server-side at `document`, then at success of `$.getScript` call `$.ajax(/*options*/)`. Could also possibly utilize web workers to update variables at original `document` when `js` is updated at server-side.

Comment: It's an interesting question, I'm not aware of any strategies that are used. You can probably wait when user is inactive for certain period of time and then reload the page if update polling returns with something.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions include

- calling `$.getScript()` to retrieve, update variables at `document` from at server-side to match variables at `document` before calling `$.ajax(/* settings */)` ;
- alternatively could use web workers to update original `document` variables to match server-side variables at `beforeSend` of `$.ajax(/* settings */)`

At result of first step of either approach, abort `$.ajax()` call, call error handlers, notify user, send message to server about error.

Comment: No, the changes are way too complex to do a 'fixer-upper' to the js. The only way to get the JS back into sync is to reload the page and, with it, the new JS. The question is how to do this in a nice way that doesn't require too much extra code or polling or a bad user experience.

Comment: @user984003 What do you mean by "way too complex"? How would calling `$.getScript()` be different than reloading page? Is `html` of `document` changed as well?

Comment: @user984003 If only option is to reload page not sure what Question is?

Comment: I wrote an edit to the question explaining why this is not what I'm looking for, but thanks.

Comment: You could use a web worker to continuously update document by calling server, updating objects, functions, listeners at `document`. Or use `confirm()` to ask user if it is ok to refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
      scripts = {};
  function load_script(name){
    var myscript = document.createElement('script');
    myscript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    myscript.setAttribute("src", name);
    if (scripts[name]) head.replaceChild(myscript, scripts[name]);
    else head.appendChild(myscript);
    scripts[name] = myscript;
  }

  // the first call to load the script code
  // and then call if you decide to upgrade a newer version
  load_script('js1.js');
  load_script('js2.js');
```

Comment: I wrote an edit to the question explaining why this is not what I'm looking for, but thanks.

Comment: I would probably be added header to each Ajax response, e.g. "js_timestamp"="16-04-2016@00-55-26"